# Mocha spies returns callCount 0

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I am using mocha, chai and sinon for unit testing in node env. I need to test a scenario where it makes a call to services to fetch the data and return the data.

My controller looks like this:

```
{
   get model() { return schema},
   async findUser(data) {
      const data = await this.model.find({ id: data.id });
      return data;
   }
}
```

In my mocha test I am using the Sinon stub to return the model and find function some like this:

```
sinon.stub(controller, 'model').get(() => ({
    find: () => ({ username: 'asdf' })
}));
```

My test is working as expected. Now I want to test see if my find method id called once and the arguments passed to it. To do that, i added following code

```
const spyFind = sinon.spy(controller.model, 'find');
assert.isTrue(spyFind.calledOnce);
```

This should return true because the spyFind is called and it returned the expected mock value. But when i debug, the spyFind object says isCalled 'false'. Can someone help me understand what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what `controller.method` is referring to. Did you mean `const spyFind = sinon.spy(controller.model, 'find');`?

Comment: Ohh yeah, updated. it is `controller.model`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your stub is designed it is going to return a new object every time `controller.model` is called. As result:

```
controller.model === controller.model // false
```

So when you try to spy on the `find` property of `controller.model` with:

```
const spyFind = sinon.spy(controller.model, 'find');
```

Sinon grabs the object returned by `controller.model` and stubs `find` on *that* object. The the next time you call `controller.model`, for example in your test, you will get a fresh object from  `controller.model` that is not spied on. So the original spy is never called.

I think  better approach is to provide a singe stub that is returned by `find()`, then you can tell if the stub is called:

```
const sinon = require('sinon')

let controller = {
    get model() { return schema},
    async findUser(data) {
        const data = await this.model.find({ id: data.id });
    return data;
    }
}

let findStub = sinon.stub()
findStub.returns({ username: 'asdf' })

sinon.stub(controller, 'model').get(() => ({
    find: findStub
}));

console.log(controller.model.find()) // { username: 'asdf' }
console.log(findStub.calledOnce);    // true
```